# There are unresolved includes inside <iostream>

Tags: c++

I just tried to compile my C++ code and an error appears when I try to do so.

The error appears on line 9

[image]

Here are the versions of the gcc and g++ and such

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit:

I am also including Movie.h:
[image]

And also Movie.cpp:

https://puu.sh/vb53G/9e9abd1832.png (I was not able to include more than 3 images due to restrictions)

Comment: The errors are in the 'Movie' class, not in the include

Comment: You need to post an MCVE. Without the relevant code pertaining to your question, we are limited in our ability to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Firstly**, in your Movie.h file, you have not included the *string header file* correctly. It should be:

```
#include <string> // without the .h extension
```

> *error: 'string' does not name a type*

**Secondly**, you have forgotten to add the closing parenthesis of the constructor function of class "Movie". I am assuming that you have added this now, after the edit

As for the marking done by your compiler, you may find the following StackOverflow post helpful:

> [**StackOverflow Post: Unresolved inclusion *iostream*.**](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/200049/)

The link is for the Eclipse IDE, but you can find a similar solution for your own IDE (I cannot tell which one you have).

Comment: When I am in Movie.h and hover over #include <string.h>, it says that there are uresolved includes inside string.h. When I ctrl+click on that it takes me to string.h and says that it could not include file <stddef.h>

Comment: Read my answer, you should do `#include <string>` not `#include <string.h>`

Comment: I just tried that, still when I hover over #include <string> it comes up with unresolved includes inside #include <string>. The error comes up as https://puu.sh/vb9Jx/7648e5101b.png. I am sorry if I am missing something blatantly obvious but I just can not figure out what the issue is.

Comment: @Exicode Try moving the `using namespace std;` under the include statements.

Comment: @Exicode If that didn't work, then visit this link: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1070816/ . I don't know which IDE _you_ are using, bu this is for Eclipse

Comment: Just tried that, still no luck. Can I just add that I reinstalled Cygwin both the 32bit version and the 64bit version. Made sure that gcc/g++ and gcc-core are the same version, I saw this fix in another post on this website but that still did not fix my issue. Having said that, this could not be in anyway related to the error that I am getting and could just be the code.

Comment: @Exicode Try creating a new project, and when you get the sample main.cpp file, paste your code in there and run it.

Comment: I tried creating a new project. The code from my other project did not run, I also tried to run a simple "Hello World" program too and although that one compiled, I still got an error when I hover over #include <iostream> saying: https://puu.sh/vbaJa/167b1a8350.png. I am using NetBeans IDE for C++, but I will now have a look at the link you sent to see if I can see anything that could help me.

Comment: @Exicode In my opinion, this looks like a compiler issue. Sincd I've not used NetBeans, I frankly cannot provide deep insight into this issue. However, if you want, you can consider switching IDEs

Comment: I will try to reinstall Netbeans and Cygwin and see if that helps. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Exicode Consider installing another IDE, like CodeBlocks, Visual Studio, or eclipse. Therre isn't as much help available for the netbeans IDE as there is for other such IDEs. I'm not trying to downvote netbeans or anything, but just offering a suggestion here.

Comment: By the way, if my tips we helpful, then please select the checkmark next to my answer. It should turn green when you do so. Thanks!

Comment: Also, you can consider installing MinGW. Many of the tutorials on how to install IDEs include demos on installing MinGW. And again, I'm not downmarketing Cgywin, but just wanted to provide this suggestion

Comment: So, in the end I decided to use Visual Studio instead and that is the fix for me. Did not find any fix to the problem I've had with Netbeans but I am hoping that this will help someone else with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

The line under the #include  is just a warning (I'm not sure why).
However, the errors are from the "Movie" class:
1. add "using namespace std" on the top of this class.
2. close the parenthesis on the constructor of 'Movie'.

Comment: I have included Movie.h as well as Movie.cpp as an edit to the original question. When I am in Movie.h and hover over #include <string.h>, it says that there are uresolved includes inside string.h. When I ctrl+click on that it takes me to string.h and says that it could not include file <stddef.h>.

Comment: <string.h> is for C. try to replace it with <string>.

Answer (score 0):

The error messages are fairly clear:

```
'string' does not name a type
```

That is, the compiler is unaware of the type `string` because either:

- you have not `#include <string>` in `Movie.h`
- or you have, but have not brought it into your namespace with a `using namespace std;`

  - although why not just refer to it as `std::string`?

Answer (score -2):

You are missing

```
#include <string>
```